# In the year 2016 how does one restart mysql daemon on MAC OS X Sierra

Tags: mysql, macos

I am running Server version: 5.7.16 Homebrew. I tried

```
sudo launchctl unload -F ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
```

but get an error message

```
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.16/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist: Could not find specified service
```

Googling is not working because there are millions of answers and none of them work.

This is a request for OSX. Not ubuntu.

Comment: Depends on the version you are using. `mysql --version` on Linux. Hope this helps ^^-d

Comment: If it's being managed by launchctl, `sudo launchctl list` should help find the service name

Comment: Tried `brew services restart mysql `?

Comment: So how did you start it?

Comment: Probably by running the services command after installation @halfelf. The installer spits out a one-liner to set up the service for auto run and immediate start. Might not be the sort of thing one would remember doing if it was a while ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Homebrew they suggest

```
brew services restart mysql
```

here: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/starting-and-stopping-background-services-with-homebrew

Comment: 3rd time's a charm, eh :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you got it working, but just for the record I'm pretty sure the answer is: don't use `sudo`. When you run `launchctl` as root, it manages launch daemons, not launch agents; you have the mysql .plist in ~/Library/LaunchAgents, so it's a per-user launch agent, not a launch daemon, and so you must run `launchctl` under your user ID (*not* root) in order to manage it.